# Adding date to my output in this below ps script

Tags: powershell-2.0

Right now below is my script

```
foreach ($Server in (Get-Content C:\psfiles\Winservers.txt)){
    Get-WmiObject win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName $Server | Select @{
        Expression={$Server};label="ServerName"},DeviceID,Volumename ,@{Expression={
        $_.Size /1Gb -as [int]};Label="Total Size(GB)"},@{Expression={($_.Size /1Gb 
        -as [int])
        - ($_.Freespace/ 1Gb -as [int])};Label="InUse Size (GB)"} ,
           @{Expression={$_.Freespace / 1Gb -as     [int]};Label="FreeSize(GB)"},
           @{Expression={(($_.Freespace /1Gb -as [float]) / ($_.Size / 1Gb -as               
           [float]))*100};Label="FreeSpace (%)"},$(Get-Date -format 'd') 
        | format-table
```

right now..i get the output as below

```
servername  deviceid  volumename  totalsize............10/6/2014 

srv1           c:       data          100                 null

srv2            d:      bkup           50                  null
```

I want to get the result as

```
servername       deviceid volumename totalsize............createdt 

srv1                c:       data          100            10/16/2014 

srv2                d:        bkup          50             10/6/2014
```

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see between the two, is the formatting spaces, and the last column with the dates.

First place [Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx) in front, before labeling all the properties. The [Get-Date](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) function just returns the current date. That's why your not seeing dates in the column.

Here's a [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx), that shows you how to format, and label the tables properly.

Comment: No actually first result i get date as column name i want it as create date and the acutal date in the column as in the second result.